# JavaScript: Convert time stamp without time zone to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, postgresql, datetime

I got stuck converting below time stamp to milliseconds in JavaScript.

I have time stamp in Postgres DB as

```
   2019-02-04 15:38:22.529
```

I get above time stamp in below format in UI when I read from DB

```
   Mon Feb 04 2019 10:38:22 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)
```

How can I convert above UI format time stamp to milliseconds in JavaScript?

Comment: Use [Date#getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) ? > A number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00

Comment: That worked well. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Use of `Date`  [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getTime)  function will return time milliseconds since `2019-02-04 15:38:22.529`:

```js
const date = new Date("2019-02-04 15:38:22.529");

const time = date.getTime();
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the "Z" means UTC+0:

```
const time = new Date("2019-02-04T15:38:22.529Z").getTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getMilliseconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) if you want milliseconds according to local time

```js
const date = new Date("2019-02-04 15:38:22.529");

const time = date.getMilliseconds()
console.log(time);
```